# Using Android's AudioTrack

Tags: android, loops, record, playback, audiotrack

I've written an app that's basically a beat pad, onscreen an array of buttons appears and you can press each button to make a different sound, I'm trying to implement another button to record these sounds then play them back when you press another button, but even with the documentation I can't figure out how to create, initialze, and record with and AudioTrack object.  Any help?

Here's my attempt at initializing:

```
tracker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 4410 , 4,2, AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(samplerateinHz, channelconfig, audioformat),AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an object of AudioRecord. AudioTrack is used for playback.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html